# Countdown using vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, countdown

I have this web page with a `textarea` and 3 `buttons`. The `textarea` receives a number. The first `button` starts the coutdown from the number to 0, with a delayed output (one number per second, so if N is 10 it'll take 10 seconds). The second `button` pauses the countdown, and the third `button` resumes it (without starting over). Pressing the first `button` at any time during the execution restarts the coutdown with whatever number is in the `textarea`. This is the code I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <h2>Insert a number:</h2>
        <textarea id="input"></textarea>
        <br/>
        <button id="start" onclick="begin()">BEGIN</button>
        <button id="pause" onclick="pause()">PAUSE</button>
        <button id="resume" onclick="resume()">RESUME</button>
        <h1 id="result"></h1>
        <script>
            var isCounting=true,
                input=document.getElementById("input"),
                countSec;
            function begin() {
                countSec=input.value;
                if (isNaN(countSec)) alert("NaN");
                count();
            }
            function pause() {
                isCounting=false;
            }
            function resume() {
                isCounting=true;
                count();
            }
            function count() {
                var i,
                    bck=countSec;
                for (i=0; i<=bck; i++) {
                    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=countSec;
                    countSec--;
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is there a way to stop the execution for 1 second after `countSec--`? I've been trying for 2 hours to do something with Date objects and setTimeout but I just can't figure out how to pause after every `for` iteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option:

```
    <script>
        var input=document.getElementById("input"),
            countSec,
            timer = null;

        function begin() {
            countSec=input.value;
            if (isNaN(countSec)) alert("NaN");
            if( timer === null ) {
                timer = setTimeout( count, 1000 );
            }
        }

        function pause() {
            clearTimeout( timer );
            timer = null;
        }

        function resume() {
            if( timer === null ) {
                timer = setTimeout( count, 1000 );
            }
        }

        function count() {
            if( countSec > 0 ) {
                countSec--;
            }

            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = countSec;

            if( countSec > 0 ) {
                timer = setTimeout( count, 1000 );
            }
        }
    </script>
```

As `begin` is called it sets a timer on `count` after 1 second.

When later `count` is invoked it decreases the counter, updates the html and schedules itself to be recalled after 1 second with `setTimeout()` (unless -of course- the counter reached zero)

The scheduled task is stored into `timer` so it can be canceled with `clearTimeout()` (see `pause()`)

To resume the countdown just call `count()` again.

`timer` is set to `null` when the counter is not running and is checked before starting it to ensure only **one** counter is running.

Comment: just a small thing, your code does `countSec--` before outputting the first number, so I had to change the first line of the begin function with `countSec=parseInt(input.value)+1`

Comment: yes, your're right! You could also use `setTimeout` on `begin`. As you already figured out a fix I'll edit the answer with this second one.

Comment: Also, different istances of the `count()` function start running at the same time if you press the begin button twice, and as a result the countdown is faster than normal. Or at least that's what I believe is happening, I'm still kinda new to `setInterval` and `setTimeout`. Anyways, I added `clearTimeout(timer);` under `countSec--` in the first `if` block in the `count` function and it (magically?) works

Comment: sure... this can be fixed by setting `timer` to `null` when the timer is not running and start it again only if `timer===null`; will update in a moment

Answer (score 1):

If you need a delay between each subtraction of countSec, then I recommend you use the `setInterval` function. I've modified your code as follows:

```
var isCounting=true,
    input=document.getElementById("input"),
    countSec
    interval;
function begin() {
    countSec=input.value;
    if (isNaN(countSec)) alert("NaN");
    count();
}
function pause() {
    isCounting=false;
    clearInterval(interval);
}
function resume() {
    isCounting=true;
    count();
}
function count() {
    var i,
        bck=countSec;

    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=bck;               

    interval = setInterval(function() {
        countSec--;
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=countSec;               
    }, 1000);
}
```

Specifically, I created a global `interval` variable, which will keep a reference to the interval. I set the interval in count(), and then I update the `#result` ID at every tick of the interval (which has a delay of 1000ms). To pause, I clear the interval. I left a lot of your code in tact even though some of it isn't being used (like isCounting);

Here's the code in action: https://jsfiddle.net/exex7jh0/

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the perfect scenario to implement Javascript's built-in asynchronous interval operations.

Your timer should center around `setInterval` ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval ). Basically, you'll set up your interval to fire every second, which will increment your counter.

To pause your countdown, you'll want to use `clearInterval` ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval ). You can also use the intervalID to determine whether the setInterval timer is running or not.

These building blocks should get you going. If you require more information, just ask.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is for your `count` function to contain a self invoking timer, like this:

```
var timer;

function count() {
    var result = document.getElementById("result");

    step();

    function step() {
        result.innerHTML=countSec;
        countSec--;
        if (countSec > 0) {
            timer = setTimeout(step, 1000);
        }
    }
}
```

But know that the timeout doesn't really count 1000ms. If you want to be accurate you'll have to compare to the time where it all began. and lower the interval:

```
var timer,
    start,
    moment,
    input = document.getElementById("input"),
    result = document.getElementById("result");

function begin() {
    var from = ((parseInt(input.value) + 1) * 1000);
    start = Date.now() + from;
    setTimeout(count, 40);
}

function pause() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
}

function resume() {
    start = Date.now() + (moment * 1000);
    count();
}

function count() {
    moment = parseInt((start - Date.now()) / 1000);
    result.innerHTML = moment;
    if (moment > 0) {
        timer = setTimeout(count, 200);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think most of the solutions have already answered your question. It is a better idea to involve interval operations in your solution as that is more apt and JS already provides it.

- Also a better idea to separate out your JS and HTML. (By avoiding inline event handlers)

**HTML**

```
<h2>Insert a number:</h2>
<textarea id="input"></textarea>
<br/>
<button id="start">BEGIN</button>
<button id="pause">PAUSE</button>
<button id="resume">RESUME</button>
<h1 id="result"></h1>
```

**JS**

```
// Bind the click events
document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('click', begin);
document.getElementById('pause').addEventListener('click', pause);
document.getElementById('resume').addEventListener('click', resume);

var input = document.getElementById("input");
var countSec;
var timer;

function begin() {
  debugger;
  countSec = input.value;
  if (isNaN(countSec)) alert("NaN");
  count();
  enableTimer();
}

function pause() {
  clearInterval(timer);
}

function resume() {
  enableTimer();
}

function count() {
  if (countSec >= 0) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = countSec;
  } else {
    clearInterval(timer);
  }
  countSec--;
}

// enable the timer again 
function enableTimer() {
   timer = setInterval(function() {
      count();
    }, 1000);
}
```

**[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zcyrv5ga/)**

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval), an intervalID  and [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval), when the count reaches zero.

```js
var isCounting = true,
    input = document.getElementById("input"),
    countSec,
    intervalID;

function begin() {
    countSec = +input.value;
    if (isNaN(countSec)) {
        alert("NaN");
        return;
    }
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = countSec;
    intervalID = setInterval(count, 1000);
}

function pause() {
    isCounting = false;
}

function resume() {
    isCounting = true;
}

function count() {
    if (countSec === 0) {
        clearInterval(intervalID);
        return;
    }
    if (isCounting) {
        countSec--;
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = countSec;
    }
}
```

```html
<h2>Insert a number:</h2>
<textarea id="input"></textarea><br/>
<button id="start" onclick="begin()">BEGIN</button>
<button id="pause" onclick="pause()">PAUSE</button>
<button id="resume" onclick="resume()">RESUME</button>
<h1 id="result"></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres another solution

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <body>
    <h2>Insert a number:</h2>
    <textarea id="input"></textarea>
    <br/>
    <button id="start" onclick="begin()">BEGIN</button>
    <button id="pause" onclick="pause()">PAUSE</button>
    <button id="resume" onclick="resume()">RESUME</button>
    <h1 id="result"></h1>
    <script>
      let isCounting = true;
      let input = document.getElementById("input");
      let countSec = 0;
      let countDownInterval = false;

      function begin() {
        countSec = input.value;
        if (isNaN(countSec)) alert("NaN");
        count();
      }

      function pause() {
        isCounting = false;
      }

      function resume() {
        isCounting = true;
      }

      function count() {
        // Let's check we're doing a restart 
        if (countDownInterval) {
          clearInterval(countDownInterval);
        }

        countDownInterval = setInterval(function() {
          if (isCounting) {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = countSec;
            countSec -= 1;
            // Times up ??
            if (countSec == -1) {
              clearInterval(countDownInterval);
              countDownInterval = null;
            }
          }
        }, 1000);
      }

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6kykz1oh/)